# Looking for an api to search for songs and artist?

Tags: api, music

I want an api that I can make an autofill feature with. So it would for the search 'b' return the most popular artists/songs starting with b and so on. I am looking to make an ios app with this.

Comment: see [datalist](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_datalist.asp) and [demo](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_datalist)